# Which G-structures lead to analyticity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

It’s well known that integrability conditions on $G$-structures *sometimes* force a unique analytic structure on the underlying manifold:

1. A Lie group structure (a 1-structure with equivariantly constant torsion) forces analyticity.
2. A complex structure (a torsion-free $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$-structure) forces analyticity.
3. A Riemannian structure (a $\operatorname{O}(n)$-structure, which happen to be always torsion-free) doesn’t lead to analyticity.
4. A symplectic structure (a torsion-free $\operatorname{Sp}(n)$-structure) doesn’t lead to analyticity.

So, what is in common between structures that do lead to analyticity, and is there a general criterion for this?

Comment: A complex structure is a $G$-structure together with the added integrability hypothesis of vanishing torsion. It is not known if the existence of a $G$-structure, for $G=\operatorname{GL}_{n/2}$, suffices for the existence of a complex structure. Similarly, a Lie group structure is a parallelism whose torsion is constant. So I think the question you have in mind is: which $G$-invariant equations on the torsion of all $G$-structures are satisfied only by real analytic $G$-structures?

Comment: @Ben McKay, thanks, I don’t know enough to state the question rigorously, but that sounds right.

Comment: @BenMcKay and of course you're right, there needs to be an additional integrability condition (although it's not obvious to me that it must always be a condition on the torsion). What you said is a very helpful way of looking at this, and clearly there's some unifying principle at work.

Comment: I meant to write $\operatorname{GL}_{n/2}\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There is also the notion of $(X,G)$ structure, where $G$ is a pseudogroup of local homeomorphisms of $X$ and it works best in the presence of analyticity, that is when an element of $G$ is determined by what it does on an open set. Analytic continuation leads to the notion of  a developing map, an immersion from the universal cover of an $(X, G)$ manifold $M$ into $X$ that is equivariant under its holonomy representation $\pi_1(M)\to G$.

Comment: I don't know enough geometry even to begin thinking about this, but I notice that your example with $G$ complex forces analyticity, and your examples with $G$ compact (at least, I assume that's what [$\operatorname{Sp}(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group#Sp(n)) means) doesn't.  Is that a coincidence?

Comment: @LSpice as Ben noted above, a Lie group is a 1-structure, so it's also compact, and yet it forces analyticity.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1212426), on the other hand, the trivial group is also a complex group.